# Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 ,Getting error: [2268] Designer process terminated unexpectedly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, windows-store-apps

Suddenly I am getting these error with VS 2013 Update 4, and not able to run or create any windows store application please help, whenever i try to open MainWindow.xaml file i get this error, below log is from event viewer.

Solution i tried:
1) cleaning "ShadowCache" folder
2) cleaning bin/obj folders & re-build solution file again
3) reinstall VS 2013 2 times (wasted ~3 hrs)

Please suggest.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <Events><Event xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event'><System><Provider Name='Application Error'/><EventID Qualifiers='0'>1000</EventID><Level>2</Level><Task>100</Task><Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords><TimeCreated SystemTime='2015-03-24T17:24:34.000000000Z'/><EventRecordID>17507</EventRecordID><Channel>Application</Channel><Computer>Win8</Computer><Security/></System><EventData><Data>XDesProc.exe</Data><Data>12.0.31101.0</Data><Data>54547532</Data><Data>combase.dll</Data><Data>6.3.9600.17031</Data><Data>53086d7c</Data><Data>c000027b</Data><Data>000fb152</Data><Data>af0</Data><Data>01d06657643c8c6c</Data><Data>C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Designer\ShadowCache\m20nnvmy.4xp\cgpsx2v3.qbv\XDesProc.exe</Data><Data>C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\combase.dll</Data><Data>a30e0668-d24a-11e4-9c3b-00235a907eef</Data><Data>App.afdf27723.a2e7a.a4ac6.ab6f8.a91e8d9764317_1.0.0.0_x86_NorthAmerica_8wekyb3d8bbwe</Data><Data>Designer.App</Data></EventData><RenderingInfo Culture='en-US'><Message>Faulting application name: XDesProc.exe, version: 12.0.31101.0, time stamp: 0x54547532
Faulting module name: combase.dll, version: 6.3.9600.17031, time stamp: 0x53086d7c
Exception code: 0xc000027b
Fault offset: 0x000fb152
Faulting process id: 0xaf0
Faulting application start time: 0x01d06657643c8c6c
Faulting application path: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Designer\ShadowCache\m20nnvmy.4xp\cgpsx2v3.qbv\XDesProc.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\combase.dll
Report Id: a30e0668-d24a-11e4-9c3b-00235a907eef
Faulting package full name: App.afdf27723.a2e7a.a4ac6.ab6f8.a91e8d9764317_1.0.0.0_x86_NorthAmerica_8wekyb3d8bbwe
Faulting package-relative application ID: Designer.App</Message><Level>Error</Level><Task>Application Crashing Events</Task><Opcode>Info</Opcode><Channel></Channel><Provider></Provider><Keywords><Keyword>Classic</Keyword></Keywords></RenderingInfo></Event></Events>
```

Screen shot is attached for your reference.
http://tinypic.com/r/lcwah/8

Comment: I feel for you as these things are frustrating has heck.

Comment: have you tried running Visual Studio "as administrator"?

Comment: @Claies, Yes i tried running with Admin privilege also and as I mentioned, it was working properly earlier with same user & suddenly started getting mentioned error.

Comment: Can you open windows store app in your windows 8?

Comment: @crea7or:  I am using VS 2013 on Win8.1.

Comment: ok, can you open Windows Store app?

Comment: No crea7or, I am not able to open & run windows store app as well